# iOS 16 deprecation of asset.duration

Tags: ios, swift, avasset, ios16

Using Xcode 14.0, iOS 16, Swift 5.7,

I get the following deprecation warning due to iOS 16:

> 'duration' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Use load(.duration) instead

Here is my code:

```swift
var actualTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: asset.duration.timescale)
```

What do I need to change in order to get rid of this warning?

I tried:

```swift
var actualTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: asset.load(.duration).timescale)
```

But this makes everything async. Do I really need to go down that road?

Comment: Adopting `async/await` is *going upstairs*. Please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets/loading_media_data_asynchronously

Answer (score 9):

```
let duration = try await asset.load(.duration)
```